# Периодически зависает Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server

Иногда, периодически происходит зависание сервера под управлением Windows Server 2003.В логах после этих зависаний появляется запись :Сбой при инициализации из-за отказа транспорта открыть начальные адреса.Сбрасывал\переустанавливал протокол tcp\ip, удалял сетевую карту и снова ставил.Но проблема осталась.Кстати этот компьютер является сервером в сети (файлохранилище).смотрел вот [здесь](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/123981), вот только немного не понял в пункте "Решение" как это сделать.во вкладке WINS свойств TCP\IP, в параметрах BetBIOS, как включал так и отключал "включить NetBIOS через TCP\IP ".но проблем осталась.Спасибо за рекомендации.

Comment: Я долго мучился с похожими проблемами, надоело и я пересел на Linux, теперь не имею этих проблем. Изучать ошибки Windows дело неблагодарное, к сожалению! Так что, коллега, искренне рекомендую Вам рассмотреть такой вариант решения... Тем более файл-сервер на Linux - то что доктор прописал.

Comment: А может просто переустановите WinSrv2003?Если файл-сервер - это файловая помойка - то да, можно и линух, а вот если там надо сложные разграничение по ACL группам и пользователям, то линух - это геморой.p.s. лучше читайте статью указанную вами на исходном языке, а не в автопереводе.

Comment: понял Вас.спасибо.хотя перестановку системы относительно недавно делал.

Answer (score 3):

Многие обычные-привычные антивирусы на этой ОС не работают. А специальные серверные версии антивирусов - слишком дороги. Однако есть ряд программ, которыми можно "почистить" эту ОС. Подозреваю, что вы какую-то заразу подцепили. С флешки или из интернета. Я слежу за здоровьем аналогичной ОС и она у меня нормально работает с 2007-го года. Так что ценность совета перехода на линукс - сомнительна.